# International characters in Spotify app tabs

Tags: spotify

International charactars, like **åäö**, won't display correct when used as tab titles in my Spotify app. A question mark is shown instead. Any clues?

Comment: Make sure your files are saved as UTF-8.

Comment: The tabs will not even show if I save as UTF-8. Must save as Unicode. Strange.

Comment: Is this in the manifest? Save as UTF-8 and also make sure there's no BOM in the file — BOMs trip up the manifest parser.

Comment: Yes, index.html could be saved as UTF-8 but if I save the manifest file as UTF-8 the tabs won't show at all. I use UltraEdit to save as UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

The encoding should be **UTF-8**. From the [Spotify Developer Guidelines](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/developer/):

> Every application must contain a file called manifest.json at the root level of the application. This file should contain a JSON dictionary, providing details about the application and its requirements. Make sure that the encoding of this file is UTF–8, or it won’t parse correctly.

I have tried it myself and it renders properly all the characters.